# Best way to prevent duplicate rows in database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernate , looking for best practice for avoid that same insert in database. I wrote program witch saves results of search from API depends on user input, when input is the same I have duplicated rows without id in database. It's problematic for me because in future uses.
Each insert must be UNIQUE.

Part of entity model :

```
@Entity
@Component
public class Flight {

    private Long id;

    private String departure;

    private String currency;

    private String destination;

    private BigDecimal price;
... etc //
```

Save code:

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String save(
                @ModelAttribute("FlightDTO") FlightDTO flightDTO,
                @ModelAttribute("FlightOutput") Map<String, Map<String, FlightDeserialization>> flightOutputMap,
                @ModelAttribute("HotelOutput") ArrayList<Comparison> hotelOutputList,
                @ModelAttribute("HotelGooglePlaceList") Map<Integer, List<PlacesResults>> hotelGooglePlaceList,
                @ModelAttribute("HotelGoogleImageList") Map<Integer, List<Imageresults>> hotelGoogleImageList) {


            boolean isHotelGoogleListEqualToHotelOutputList = hotelGooglePlaceList.keySet().size() == hotelOutputList.size() & hotelGooglePlaceList.keySet().size() == hotelGoogleImageList.size();


            Flight flight;
            for (String keyOut : flightOutputMap.keySet()) {

                for (String keyIn : flightOutputMap.get(keyOut).keySet()) {
                    flight = new Flight();
                    flight.setCurrency(flightDTO.getCurrency());
                    flight.setAirline(csvParser.airlineParser(flightOutputMap.get(keyOut).get(keyIn).getAirline()));
                    flight.setAirlineIata(flightOutputMap.get(keyOut).get(keyIn).getAirline());
                    flight.setDepartureTime(flightOutputMap.get(keyOut).get(keyIn).getDepartureTime());
                    flight.setReturnTime(flightOutputMap.get(keyOut).get(keyIn).getReturnTime());
                    flight.setFlightNumber(flightOutputMap.get(keyOut).get(keyIn).getFlightNumber());
                    flight.setPrice(flightOutputMap.get(keyOut).get(keyIn).getPrice());
                    flight.setExpiresAt(flightOutputMap.get(keyOut).get(keyIn).getExpiresAt());
                    flight.setDestination(flightDTO.getDestination());
                    flight.setDeparture(flightDTO.getDeparture());
                    flight.setUserName(CurrentUserName().getUsername());

                    if (isHotelGoogleListEqualToHotelOutputList) {
                        Hotel hotel;
                        BigDecimal exchangeRate = currencyRepository.findByName(flightDTO.getCurrency()).getExchangeRate();
                        for (int i = 0; i < hotelOutputList.size(); i++) {
                            Comparison array = hotelOutputList.get(i);
                            hotel = new Hotel();


                            hotel.setImage(hotelGoogleImageList.get(i).get(1).getImage());
                                            hotel.setHotelLink(hotelGoogleImageList.get(i).get(0).getLink());



                            hotel.setLatitude(hotelGooglePlaceList.get(i).get(0).getGps_coordinates().getLatitude());
                            hotel.setLongitude(hotelGooglePlaceList.get(i).get(0).getGps_coordinates().getLongitude());


hotel.setCurrency(flightDTO.getCurrency());
hotel.setName(array.getHotel());
hotel.setSite(array.getVendor1());
hotel.setSite(array.getVendor2());
                            hotel.setPrice(hotelCurrencyService.amountCalculator(array.getVendor1Price(), exchangeRate));
                            hotel.setPrice(hotelCurrencyService.amountCalculator(array.getVendor2Price(), exchangeRate));
                            hotel.setPrice(hotelCurrencyService.amountCalculator(array.getVendor3Price(), exchangeRate));


flight.setHotel(hotel);
flightRepository.save(flight);
```

I have tried used @UniqueConstraint , and @Unique, but I guess it intended for something else.

Please Help me !

Comment: Create unique constraint in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need `@Component` on your entity.

Second, add this annotation

```
@Table(name = "table_name", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames ={"id", "departure", ...})})
```

with fields that should not be duplicated.

NB: you need to add `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` to application.properties

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update after added it WORKS ! Thank You!

Comment: Bor has already given the answer but I just want to add something, you can also specify `@Column(unique = true) private int id;` at the field level, you will also have more control for such as *nullable*, *updateable* etc

Answer (score 0):

Adding `@UniqueConstraint` to the ORM does not help as hibernate won't check for uniqueness. There are two ways - add a unique constraint to the database table and/or implement duplicate entry check yourself in code.

In case you add the unique constraint to the database table handle constraint violation exception.

Comment: Why not? `@UniqueConstraint` should create unique index for declared fields, isn't it?

Comment: @BorLaze In case DDL is not generated, the unique index won't be created. Why not do this in table definition at the first place if the OP is not generating DDL from ORM?

Comment: I don't know but when I have added it to the application properties inteliji yelling that is it unused property.

Comment: @GrafikKrystian, did you try `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`?